# LayoutInflater trouble

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter, layout-inflater

In my app I read data from a file store it in an arraylist. Each object within the arraylist consists of two pieces of data. I wanted to show each piece of data as a separate TextView and two TextViews per row for the listView I am creating. So I created a custom BaseAdapter, but I am having difficulty in implementing the View methold.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d("MyAdapter","getItemId successful");
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Log.d("MyAdapter","layout inflater successful");
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
    Log.d("MyAdapter","view row successful");

    TextView Course = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView Points = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Row temp =rowList.get(position);
    Course.setText(temp.course);
    Points.setText(temp.points);
    /*for(int i =0; i<rowList.size();i++){
    Row r = rowList.get(i);
    course.setText(r.course);
    points.setText(r.points);
    }*/
    return row;
```

I tried creating rows using the commented out for loop, but it didn't work so I tried following slidenerds videos on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_l9e2t4fcfM), but it did not work for me. When I run my application, it doesn't make it past

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

or else it would have said "layout inflater successful", because of the Log statement. I believe the error has something to do with the LayoutInflater, but I have no idea how to go about fixing it. Please help!

Here is my entire Adapter Class

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Row>rowList = new ArrayList<Row>();
//  LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    MyAdapter(Context c)
    {
        //String space = " ";
         Log.d("MyAdapter","adapting haha");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = c.openFileInput("GPACoursedata.txt");
            File courseDataFile = new File ("GPACoursedata.txt");
            if(courseDataFile.length()==0){

                CharSequence text = "Add Courses and grades";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast.makeText(c, text, duration).show();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer Cbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int input = -1;
        try {
            while((input = fis.read())!=-1)
            {
                Cbuffer.append((char)input);
                //Cbuffer.append((char)input);
                 Log.d("MyAdapter","Cbuffer appending...");
            }
             Log.d("MyAdapter","Cbuffer check" + Cbuffer.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(fis!=null){
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            fis = c.openFileInput("GPAPointsdata.txt");
            File courseDataFile = new File ("GPAPointsdata.txt");
            if(courseDataFile.length()==0){

                CharSequence text = " ";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast.makeText(c, text, duration).show();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer Pbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        input = -1;
        try {
            while((input = fis.read())!=-1)
            {
                Pbuffer.append((char)input);
                 Log.d("MyAdapter","Pbuffer appending...");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(fis!=null){
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Pbuffer tinka " + Cbuffer.toString());
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Cbuffer " + Cbuffer.substring(0, Cbuffer.length()-1).toString());
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Pbuffer " + Pbuffer.substring(0, Pbuffer.length()-1).toString());

        }
        ArrayList<String>Lcourses = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String>Lpoints = new ArrayList<String>();
        //int k = 0;
        //System.out.println(Cbuffer.);
        String cString = Cbuffer.substring(0,Cbuffer.length());
        Log.d("MyAdapter","substrings" + cString );
        int start =0;
        Log.d("MyAdapter","lastIndexOf" + String.valueOf(cString.lastIndexOf(" ")) );
        Log.d("MyAdapter","substrings testing" + cString.substring(0, 1) );

        while(cString.length()>1){
            start = cString.indexOf(" ") + 1;
            Lcourses.add(cString.substring(0, start));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","substrings 0 to start" + cString.substring(0, start ));
            cString=cString.substring(start,cString.length());
            Log.d("MyAdapter", "cString length "+String.valueOf(cString.length()));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","cStrings" + cString);
        }


        String pString = Cbuffer.substring(0,Pbuffer.length());
        Log.d("MyAdapter","p substrings" + pString );
        start =0;
        Log.d("MyAdapter","p IndexOf" + String.valueOf(pString.indexOf(" ")) );
        while(pString.length()>1){
            start = pString.indexOf(" ") + 1;
            Lpoints.add(pString.substring(0, start));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","substrings 0 to start" + pString.substring(0, start ));
            pString=pString.substring(start,pString.length());
            Log.d("MyAdapter", "pString length "+String.valueOf(pString.length()));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","pStrings" + pString);
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Lcourses.size" + String.valueOf(Lcourses.size()));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Lpoints.size" + String.valueOf(Lpoints.size()));


        }
        for(int j =0;j<Lcourses.size();j++){
            Lcourses.get(j).replaceAll("$"," ");
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Done fixing the dollar signs");
            //rowList.add(new Row(Lcourses.get(j),Lpoints.get(j)));
            //Log.d("MyAdapter","Done adding to rowList");
        }
        for(int j =0;j<Lcourses.size();j++){
            //Lcourses.get(j).replaceAll("$"," ");
            //Log.d("MyAdapter","Done fixing the dollar signs");
            rowList.add(new Row(Lcourses.get(j),Lpoints.get(j)));
            Log.d("MyAdapter","Done adding to rowList");
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return rowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("MyAdapter","getCount successful");

        return rowList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("MyAdapter","getItem successful");

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.d("MyAdapter","getItemId successful");
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        Log.d("MyAdapter","layout inflater successful");
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        Log.d("MyAdapter","view row successful");

        TextView course = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView points = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        for(int i =0; i<rowList.size();i++){
        Row r = rowList.get(i);
        course.setText(r.course);
        points.setText(r.points);
        }
        return row;
    }

}
```

Log Cat

```
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.example.gpatestingapp.MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:400)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-02 16:26:30.860: E/AndroidRuntime(4249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Look in the LogCat for an error message.  My first guess would be that context is null  You can try printing out  the value of context using Log.d(String.format("context = %s", context));

Comment: Post logcat please. But I'm guessing the problem is that you don't extend Activity so there is no context. Pass the context from your activity to your custom adapter

Comment: @user3897744 Did u initialized the Context variable in the constructor of the Adapter class

Comment: Yea, i didn't extend activity but I did class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{.Also I extended activity in the class that sets the adapter, so Main_Activity for me. I would post logcat, but R from andorid.R cannot be resolved as a variable (I dont think the layoutInflater issue is related and I saw threads for fixing the android.R issue even though they aren't working). I will post my entire Adapter Class.

Comment: @james, it wasn't initialized thanks, but I changed it and now that it is (context = android.app.Application@b2d9bef0)
 it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks guys it works, the issue was with me not initializing the context buts its all good now thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```